# Map values based off matched columns - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I want to map values based how two columns are matched. For instance, the df below contains different labels, `A` or `B`. I want to assign a new column that describes these labels. How this occurs is comparing columns `Z L` and `Z P`. `Z L` will always contain either `['X1','X2','X3','X4']`. While `Z P` will correspondingly contain `['LA','LB','LC','LD']`.

These will always be in acceding order or reverse order. As in ascending order will mean `X1` corresponds to `LA`, `X2` corresponds to `LB` etc. Reverse order means `X1` corresponds to `LD`, `X2` corresponds to `LC` etc.

If ascending order I want to map an `R`. If reverse order I want to map an `L`.

```
X = ['X1','X2','X3','X4']

R = ['LA','LB','LC','LD']
L = ['LD','LC','LB','LA']

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Period' : [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],        
        'labels' : ['A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B'],                  
        'Z L' : [np.nan,np.nan,'X3','X2','X4',np.nan,'X2','X3','X3','X1'],     
        'Z P' : [np.nan,np.nan,'LC','LC','LD',np.nan,'LC','LC','LB','LA'],                       
        })

df = df.dropna()
```

This is the output dataset to determine the combinations. I have a large df with repeated combinations so I'm not too concerned with returning all of them. I'm mainly concerned with all unique Mapped values for each `Period`.

```
   Period labels Z L Z P
2       1      A  X3  LC
3       1      B  X2  LC
4       1      A  X4  LD
6       2      A  X2  LC
7       2      B  X3  LC
8       2      A  X3  LB
9       2      B  X1  LA
```

Attempt:

```
labels = df['labels'].unique().tolist()

I = df.loc[df['labels'] == labels[0]]
J = df.loc[df['labels'] == labels[1]]


I['Map'] = ((I['Z L'].isin(X)) | (I['Z P'].isin(R))).map({True:'R', False:'L'})

J['Map'] = ((J['Z L'].isin(X)) | (J['Z P'].isin(R))).map({True:'R', False:'L'})
```

If I drop duplicates from period and labels the intended df is:

```
   Period labels    Map
0       1      A      R
1       1      B      L
2       2      A      L
3       2      B      R
```

Comment: How did you come-up with L for B in period 1? Since it is just one (neither ascending, nor descending)

Comment: @moys, I've included more info. Does this make sense now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my approach:

```
# the ascending orders
lst1,lst2 = ['X1','X2','X3','X4'], ['LA','LB','LC','LD']

# enumerate the orders
d1, d2 = ({v:k for k,v in enumerate(l)} for l in (lst1, lst2))

# check if the enumerations in `Z L` and `Z P` are the same
df['Map'] = np.where(df['Z L'].map(d1)== df['Z P'].map(d2), 'R', 'L')
```

Output:

```
   Period labels Z L Z P Map
2       1      A  X3  LC   R
3       1      B  X2  LC   L
4       1      A  X4  LD   R
6       2      A  X2  LC   L
7       2      B  X3  LC   R
8       2      A  X3  LB   L
9       2      B  X1  LA   R
```

and `df.drop_duplicates(['Period', 'labels'])`:

```
   Period labels Z L Z P Map
2       1      A  X3  LC   R
3       1      B  X2  LC   L
6       2      A  X2  LC   L
7       2      B  X3  LC   R
```

Answer (score 0):

You said your data is always either in ascending or reversed order. You only need to define a fix mapping between `Z L` and `Z P` as the `R` and check on this mapping. If `True` it is `R`, else `L`. I may be wrong, but I think solution may be reduced to this

```
r_dict = dict(zip(['X1','X2','X3','X4'], ['LA','LB','LC','LD']))
df1['Map'] = (df1['Z L'].map(r_dict) == df1['Z P']).map({True: 'R', False: 'L'})

Out[292]:
   Period labels Z L Z P Map
2  1       A      X3  LC  R
3  1       B      X2  LC  L
4  1       A      X4  LD  R
6  2       A      X2  LC  L
7  2       B      X3  LC  R
8  2       A      X3  LB  L
9  2       B      X1  LA  R
```

For the bottom desired output, you just `drop_duplicates` as QuangHoang.